# How to find all of the style attributes I can edit in ant design component?

Tags: css, reactjs, web-component, antd

I'm trying to create an ant design card that has a border only on the left and right side of the card. The `bordered` attribute that I can directly edit in the card component either removes the entire border or none of the border. I want to be able to specify aspects of the border in an inline style. Where/how do I find what inline style attributes I can edit?

```
<Card
    bordered={false}
    style={{
    // how do I find all of the attributes I can edit right here
    }}
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via the Development tools on the page in browser:

In the Elements panel choose the desired element and go to Styles tab:

```
<div class="ant-card ant-card-bordered" style="border-top: 1px;border-bottom: 1px;width: 300px;">
```

Styles tab:

```
.ant-card-bordered {
border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
border-top-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a css file and add those class names to the 'className' prop of 'Card' component?

You can inspect the element using Chrome dev tools and write the CSS with the class names that of your need.

You css file will be something like below: (add more specificity as per need)

```
.cardBorder {
    border: none;
}
```

And your card component like below :

```
<Card className="cardBorder" />
```

By this, you can do any kind of css modifications. More than inline styles, is better to have separate css file and handle these.

Comment: I tried this using a `className="card"` and then imported the css file with `border-top`: 10px, but instead of making the top border 10px, it got rid of the top border...